# Using forward declarations for built in datatypes

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I understand that wherever possible we shall use forward declarations instead of includes to speed up the compilation.

I have a class `Person` like this.

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

class Person
{
public:
    Person(std::string name, int age);
    std::string GetName(void) const;
    int GetAge(void) const;
private:
    std::string _name;
    int _age;
};
```

and a class `Student` like this

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

class Person;

class Student
{
public:
    Student(std::string name, int age, int level = 0);
    Student(const Person& person);
    std::string GetName(void) const;
    int GetAge(void) const;
    int GetLevel(void) const;
private:
    std::string _name;
    int _age;
    int _level;
};
```

In Student.h, I have a forward declaration `class Person;` to use `Person` in my conversion constructor. Fine. But I have done `#include <string>` to avoid compilation error while using `std::string` in the code. How to use forward declaration here to avoid the compilation error? Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: You understand wrong. as far as possible you should not use forward declarations, but include the relevant header file.

Comment: I got the idea from some articles like this. http://www-subatech.in2p3.fr/~photons/subatech/soft/carnac/CPP-INC-1.shtml

Comment: Don't believe everything you read on the internet.

Comment: Sadly, I find this tip in many sites: http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/headerfileincludepatterns.htm

Comment: If Bjarne Stroustrup tells you to do something - it's probably a good idea. If some nameless guy on the net tells you to, you should at least be somewhat sceptical.

Comment: Even a when a named guy tells you something, you should be sceptical. @Neil, I'm curious as to why you think "as far as possible you should not use forward declarations, but include the relevant header file."

Comment: Lakos's Large Scale C++ development book for instance advocates the use careful use of forward declaration to manage dependencies.  If you've ever dealt with a large C++ project and have had the need for Pimpl classes then this is really important.  It's not the compilation time as such that's the issue, but the fact that a change to one header causes a huge amount of other stuff to be rebuilt.

Comment: @Neil: could you please elaborate on your first comment?

Comment: @the_mandrill Yes, If I wre using PIMPL I would of course use forward declarations.Hence my use of the phrase "whenever possible"  in  my first comment.

Comment: @Jon Using a forward decl when not implementing the PIMPL pattern can only be to get a (usually very small) decrease in compilation times. I find the decrease is not worth the effort - I almost always need the full decl anyway.

Comment: @Neil: Just so I understand you, do you think that headers which only use a reference or pointer to a class should still #include its header rather than use a forward declaration? Apart from slower compilation, have you considered circular dependencies?

Comment: @Jon I think unless you are avoiding circular dependencies (which are quite rare) or using the PIMPL idiom (which is also not that frequently used, at least in my code) then yes, you should include the header. The differences in compile times in the cases I've measured are tiny.

Comment: @Neil some disagree: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Header_File_Dependencies

Comment: @Jon You will find *lots* of people disagree with the google style guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since used `string` as

```
std::string _name;
//^^^^^^^^^ concrete member
```

the whole structure of `string` would be needed, so the declaration must be needed. You must `#include <string>`.

---

Declaration of `string` can be omitted possible if you write, e.g.

```
std::string* _name;
//^^^^^^^^^^ pointer or reference
```

which you could use a forward declaration, but I still recommend you **not** to do so, because `std::string` is not a simple structure type like Person or Student, but a very complex type involving many templates:

```
template<class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT>, class Allocator = allocator<charT> >
class basic_string { ... };
typedef basic_string<char> string;
```

If you forward declare it wrongly (e.g. `class string;`), the compilation will fail when you actually use it because of conflicting type.

Comment: Similarly, if I pass `Person` by value, isn't the forward declaration `class Person;` sufficient?

Comment: Actually no, if you declare a function that passes an instance of class A by value, or returns it by value, and don't call any member functions on it, forward declaration *is* sufficient, because size of the class is not needed by the compiler.

Comment: "If you forward declare it wrongly"... is there any way to do it _rightly_? AFAIK it can't be done in a Standard-compliant way, at least, as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/4801442/2757035 ...and possibly not at all. But if you found some way that worked for you on an implementation-defined basis, what was it?

Answer (score 2):

You can only use forward declarations with pointers and references (because these are of a fixed size, independent of the size of the object they refer to). If you use a specific class by value, the compiler needs its full definition (in order to know its exact size), thus forward declaration is not enough.

Thus, if you define `Student` like this

```
class Student
{
public:
    ...
    Student(const Person person);
    ...
private:
    Person person;
};
```

either of the above class members would force you to `#include` Person.h in your header.

You understand well, that forward declaration helps avoiding compilation dependencies, thus reduces compilation time. However, that concerns mainly user-defined headers, because these are the ones that can change frequently. Standard library headers are not going to change, so the saving is not significant in those cases.

Comment: In fact, `GetPerson()` would not force you to include Person.h. The compiler does not need to know the size of the return type of a function in its declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use forward declarations for type identification, such as when you use the declared type in a function/method pointer parameter prototype.  If you are going to declare a member variable (i.e. std::string _name;) the compiler needs a little bit more than a forward declaration can give it.  For example, if someone does a sizeof(Student) the compiler has to have access to the entire declaration to figure out the size.

Comment: @Peter, @Amardeep - Do you mean that this `class Person;` forward declaration won't hold good if there is a member for the class `Person` in the `Student` class?

Comment: sorry, I edited your answer instead of mine :-( now rolled back.

Comment: @bdhar: Sorry about my prior comment-response... I misunderstood your question.  The answer is affirmative: If Student has a member of type Person then you must include "Person.h".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe also consider to use inheritance.

```
#include "Person.h" // i am afraid you need to

class Student : public Person
{
     ...

     protected:
         int _level;
         // no name and age, that is inhertianced from person
         // (if you want to access them from student, you maybe need to make them protected)
 };
```

Comment: Yeah sure. Thanks! But, that's a different topic altogether. I just contrived this example just to make my query clear.

Answer (score 0):

Forward declarations are used to reduce include and to resolve cyclic dependencies. But when using forwards in the public or protected interface of your class, you place the burden of including the correct header files to the users of your class.
Beside this, forwarding types defined in the STL may not work as expected. For example, std::string might be defined as `typedef basic_string<char> string;`. Declaring it forward with `namespace std{ class string;}` will give you a compilation error.