# forward declaration of class

Tags: c++

In A.h I have the following class

```
class A
{
  int a;
  char name[100];
}
```

B.h has the following code

```
class A;
Class B
{
  public:
   int c;
   float d;
   getObjectDetails(A *);
};
```

I compiled it as `g++ A.h B.h B.cpp -o out`. But it gives compilation errors saying class A is incomplete. Could any one please help me understand?

Also, if I include header file A.h in B.h, everything goes fine. In that case, I need not declare Class A before Class B definition I think, I can directly create and use instance of class A. Could anyone clarify me on this point?

what happens in step "class A" declaration at compile time and run time?

Comment: Is that your actual code?  `class A` is missing a semi-colon, `class B` miscapitalizes `class`, and no return type is specified for `getObjectDetails`.

Comment: Sorry this is not actual code, just a sample code which looks similar to actual code.

Comment: Many of them suggested to include A.h in B.cpp. If I include A.h in B.cpp, why do I need to declare class A before Class B? Is that declaration required?

Comment: You need to forward declare `class A` in B.hpp for all .cpp files that include B.hpp but not A.hpp.

Comment: @Teja: Please correct the sample code then.  You shouldn't paraphrase code (or if you do, you should *test* it); if you make mistakes when trying to simplify it, it's hard for us to tell which ones are causing your problem.

Answer (score 1):

> You can only use forward declarations
> with pointers and references (because
> these are of a fixed size, independent
> of the size of the object they refer
> to). If you use a specific class by
> value, the compiler needs its full
> definition (in order to know its exact
> size), thus forward declaration is not
> enough.
>
> You can only use forward declarations
> for type identification, such as when
> you use the declared type in a
> function/method pointer parameter
> prototype. If you are going to declare
> a member variable (i.e. std::string
> _name;) the compiler needs a little bit more than a forward declaration
> can give it. For example, if someone
> does a sizeof(Student) the compiler
> has to have access to the entire
> declaration to figure out the size.

Answer by [Péter Török](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265143/peter-torok) from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989125) thread.

Answer (score 1):

It should compile fine, if you

1) add a semi-colon at the end of class A declaration.

2) change "C" to "c" in class B declaration.

3) add a return type to getObjectDetails()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is surely in B.cpp, because B.h is fine. If you are trying to do anything with the `A*` received by `getObjectDetails()` (such as calling a method on it), the compiler will not be able to understand it.

To fix it, try including A.h in B.cpp (B.h does not need it, indeed).

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have `#include "A.h"` in `B.cpp`, which is then using A in such a way that it requires A to be defined, not just declared. Absent the definition, just about the only thing you can do with the `A*` passed to `getObjectDetails` is store it in an `A*` or `void*` variable, or pass it on to some other code outside `B.cpp`.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo, now I understood the concept. Your point clarified my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should #include A.h from B.h.  What you've done instead is called a *forward declaration*, and is only recommended when A.h either contains an enormous amount of code, or includes other files that do.  Then, the "class A;" thing can be a quick way to let your compiler know that A is a class, and hence accept pointers and reference to A objects, without parsing all the extra code from A.h.  *Your A.h is not long enough to justify such a hack.*  It is much better to directly use the authoratative source of information about A, which is A.h, instead of spreading information about A (which may one day cease to be true) throughout B.  I actively dislike this forward declaration hack, and recommend creating a dedicated forward declaration header that contains "class A;" and any other classes A.h grows to contain, so that uses like B can include that if they don't need the full declarations.  This is done by the Standard Library in , which forward declares useful classes, variables and constants for the heavier-weight .

Then, your B.cpp should #include B.h.  Your command line should simply be:

```
g++ B.cpp -o out
```

(no need to mention A.h or B.h as they will be included (indirectly and directly respectively) from B.cpp.

Comment: Will there be any major difference in adding A.h in B.cpp and compiling as "g++ B.cpp -o out" and compiling it as "g++ A.h B.h B.cpp -o out". Kindly clarify

Comment: That depends on whether you have #include "B.h" in B.cpp and #include A.h in B.h.  If you do, then your compiler will see those headers twice.  People normally put an include guard (#ifndef INCLUDED_FILENAME_H/#define INCLUDED_FILENAME_H/.../#endif) (or #pragma once) in the header to prevent this, as some headers have content that the compiler won't accept twice.  If you don't have those include statements in your files, then it won't work without specifying the headers to g++.  Still, it quickly becomes unmanageable to track the needed headers in the compile line - do use #includes.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
class A;
class B
{
public:
    int c;
    float d;
    void getObjectDetails(A *);
};
```

***compiles fine for me*** using VC9 (VS 2008) and I believe this to be correct.

If your code does not compile, it *differs from the above in a significant detail*. The only way for you to find that (there's no way for us to find it) is to take (a copy of) your original code, and start removing things step by step until the error goes away.
Either you then understand what the problem is or you end up with <20 lines of self-contained example code which reproduce the error - a perfect repro to come back here and ask about.